# target ="_blank" is not working for pdf in cromium browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

It is working on the same tab though.

```
<a href="path" class="some-class" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>
```

It is working for the file types `.html` and `.txt` but not for `.pdf` even `.docx` files get downloaded.
I am writing this code in cshtml.

I want to open a pdf document in a new tab.

Comment: In your case, You just want to show pdf in razor view?

Comment: This behavior depends on your browser settings — see how your browser is handling files of these types.

Comment: I am not sure if you mean Chrome will just download this pdf file instead of opening it in another new tag, If it is, you change this setting(chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments)

Comment: I am using cromium debbuger. I just want to show it in new tab other file types like .html, .txt is opening fine nut when i try to open .pdf type it show a blank popup just.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I do for this...

In view (.cshtml):

```
<a asp-page="/OpenFile" target="_blank" asp-route-file-id="@Model.Quotes.QuotedPart.PDF-File-ID"><img src="/images/PDF_file_icon.svg" width="30" height="30" /></a>
```

In controller (OpenFile.cs):

```
  // lookup file's stored path from DB: this becomes "filename" which in my case includes folder/filename
    var memory = new MemoryStream();
                string baseDir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
                string fullPath = baseDir + filename;
                
     using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                    }
                    memory.Position = 0;
               
                    return File(memory, "application/pdf");
```

The key seemed to be to return File object with "application/pdf" mimetype without the 3rd parameter string of filename.

Answer (score 0):

Any local downloaded file should work with "_blank" if user has not set their browser to download only (rather than download after view).

So simply point as you have done, to the a href="local.pdf" or if its remote the URL.pdf

[image]

### However

that same file in some recent chromium's like Edge may be truly a blob blank
! (so in the run up to adding Acrobat as replacing Skia/Foxit), MS ? or chromium? seem to have lost the plot?

[image]